# acceleration and velocity

Tags: calculus

I am stuck on an assignment question and am hoping someone can give me a pointer in the right direction.  The question is that a car driving at 60km/h slows to 25km/h, it was 50m from an intersection when it started slowing down.  Assume the cars acceleration is constant.

I am required to find the formulas for v(t) and s(t) and a.     Also at the moment when the car started slowing $t=0$ and $s_0=0$.

So far I have attempted to use $v^2=u^2+2as$ and solve for $a$ but when I attempt to take an integral of this equation to get $dv/dt$ it doesn't seem to work  correctly.

I understand this is a question that maybe my tutor should be answering however it takes so long for them to get back to me!
Thankyou for any help.

Comment: We have a $\Delta v$ of $35$ km/n in a distance traveleld of $0.05$ Km.

Comment: Assuming constant deceleration $a$, we have : $\Delta s= \dfrac 1 2 a (\Delta t)^2$.

Comment: Do I get you right: the car slows down to 25$\tfrac{km}{h}$ at the moment when it arrives at the intersection?

Comment: Thus : $2 (0.05) = a (\Delta t)^2$. But $a= \dfrac {\Delta v}{\Delta t}$.

Comment: so solving for $a=\Delta t^2 / 0.1$ is the equation Im looking for for $a$?

Comment: denklo: I believe so yes but its not particularly clear on that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be more precise, the formula that you use is $v(t)^2=v(0)^2+2as(t)$. I'm not sure how you tried to integrate it precisely, but you might have fixed something that's variable.

Anyway, you know the final velocity and the distance traveled, so that would give you $a$:

$$(25\,\mathrm{km/h})^2= (60\,\mathrm{km/h})^2 + 2a\cdot 50\,\mathrm{m}.$$

Now, $v(t) = at + v(0)$ and $s(t) = v(0)t + \frac 12 at^2$ and you are done.

Comment: this place is awsome!    Only one more question, in the $s(t)$ integral, what happens to the $C$ constant?

Comment: Am I correct in saying that it is $V(t)$?

Comment: @Ryan, I don't know what you mean. If you mean that $s(t) = \int_0^tv(x)\,dx$, the constant is $s_0 = 0$, by the condition in your exercise.

Comment: when I intergrate $v(t)$ I get  $s(t)=1/2 a(t)t^2+V(o)t+C$ like you said but Im not sure on the $C$ constant

Comment: @Ryan, and as I said, the condition in your exercise is that $s_0 = 0$, so your $C = 0$.

Comment: fantastic!  thankyou so much for your help!